# click on web Scraping without getting an error with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options

import unittest
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

```
#link to website
website = 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/monitoring/climate-at-a-glance'
path = ('../chromedriver') #Folder location where is the chromedriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(website) 
driver.maximize_window()

#Selection of the sections where the information I am looking for is located
state_click = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="show-statewide"]/a').click()
time_series_click = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//*[@id="time-series"]/div[3]/button').click()

#selection of the years (for all files the same range of 1950 - 2021)
star_year_dropdown =Select(driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='begyear'))
star_year_dropdown.select_by_visible_text('1950')
end_year_dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='endyear'))
end_year_dropdown.select_by_visible_text('2021')

#selection of the parameter to download: Average temperature
parameter_dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='parameter'))
parameter_dropdown.select_by_visible_text('Average Temperature')

#Creating a loop to loop through all the states and all the months:

#state selection
select_state = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//*[@id="state"]')
opcion_state = select_state.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME, value='option')

#month selection
select_month = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value = '//*[@id="month"]')
opcion_month = select_month.find_elements(by = By.TAG_NAME, value='option')

for option in opcion_month:
    option.click()

    for option in opcion_state:
        option.click()
        time.sleep(3)

        plot = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='.//input[@id="submit"]').click()
        dowload = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="csv-download"]'))).click()
        time.sleep(3)
```

The code works fine, but in the plot and download functions created (at the end of the whole) when trying to click it gives an error and cannot be solved. I think it is because the web page at the time of executing that command does not display the button in the screen to plot the graph and download the csv. I have tried modifying the waiting time, but not work. Let's see if someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem that you are having with downloading the CSV file is not that the command is wrong (it does work), however, the issue is that the download CSV button is not visible on the page, which prevents you from clicking it.

A way to get around having to visibly see the element on the page and still click it you can do the following:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="csv-download"]'))
```

This would be the preferred method, otherwise you would have to scroll to where the button is visible on the page and then click the button. The page has a scrolling effect if trying to click on a button which you can do the following (but the previous method is preferred as it is cleaner and does not take any additional time to do):

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

download_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="csv-download"]')
try:
    download_btn.click() # the first time you try to click it will throw an error, while navigating the button into the page view
except ElementClickInterceptedException: # catch the exception and proceed as if clicking again
    download_btn.click()
```

**Other comments on your code**

you have `option.click()` twice in your code, and it is unclear if you want to click the month or state option - there may be a confusion about which `options` are clicked. I would suggest renaming your iterator variables appropriately so that you know which buttons are being clicked

Comment: Thank you for your help, my problem is solved, the suggestion work perfectly. Thanks aswell for your suggestion about the code to be more clear, it's true about the `options` clicked, could be confuse. I will work to change this.